# What is a good strategy to maintain a set of binaries for Gentoo?

Tags: package-management, gentoo, packages

There is the world favourites file in which you can record your favourite packages, then there is the  where you can record packages and compile whenever. Also there is http://paludis.pioto.org/.

This is not a right or wrong question, I'm simply asking if anyone has any thoughts on maintaining a repository of binaries for Gentoo. Neat suggestions and links to blogs or whatever are most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And.. surprisingly enough (or unsurprisingly enough), gentoo supports building packages and creating a repository, using emerge, and its in [the gentoo handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-ppc64.xml?part=2&chap=3#doc_chap4) (its the PPC version, but eh, the commands should be the same, and easy to check). It also says how to set up a repository.

I'd note though, you'd lose the advantage of being able to optimise your compilation, unless all systems are of the same rough architecture, and of course, you can't share packages between different major architecture families.

Comment: I must have missed (ignored) their mention of catalyst when I read the handbook a few years ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This IS a right or wrong question. (I know I'll get modded down, but I guess I had to say it)

To maintain a binary package system for gentoo is just against its philosophy. The spirit of gentoo is its ports system, with allowed the gentoo system to be extremely portable and managable. To maintain such a binary package system for gentoo is almost like saying you want to maintain a giant insecure software repository for OpenBSD...

After all, isn't it the built from source concept that makes gentoo different?

**EDIT**:

Actually, it REALLY isn't that difficult to make it easy to maintain a set of binaries for gentoo. A simple method is to adopt e.g. rpm/dpkg for use in gentoo.

In general, though, if you have to ask (how), packaging would be very difficult you, let alone managing or adopting a binary packaging system.

Comment: Thank you for your subjective rendition of the 'ports philosophy'. Contrary to your conviction the philosophy of Gentoo is, and I quote: 'Every user has work they need to do. The goal of Gentoo is to design tools and systems that allow a user to do that work as pleasantly and efficiently as possible, as they see fit.' So if I see fit to make a binary snapshot of my system every month or so, its not in your place to criticize me from the standpoint of "That's not in Gentoo's Philosophy". Thank you, but no thank you

Comment: Unless your connection is suddenly terminated or you have selective blindness, the statement that follows your quote reads "This is only possible when the tool is designed to reflect and transmit the will of the user, and leave the possibilities open as to the final form of the raw materials (**the source code.**)" (Emphasis mine)

Comment: To say somebody as a dog is almost never a good idea. Anyways, if you think that the **raw material** of a computer program could equal binary package, gentoo is probably not for you. Good luck.

Comment: Read the text mr. polite cat. FINAL RESULT OF RAW MATERIAL. What is final result of source code to you? Not a binary package I presume. Wtf is this? Flame the new guy week? I was polite in my original reply. Don't have any suggestions on how to manage binary packages in Gentoo? -- move along and get off my back!

Comment: Final form of raw material, not final result of raw material, sir. Answer added.

Comment: I interpret "leave the possibilities open as to the final form of the raw materials" as "install the software how you want with the features you want". Imagine for example the objective of making a "distribution of Gentoo" for say.. eee pc 1004HA. Would you give potential users instructions on how to build the system from scratch or distribute software binaries with a compiled kernel? I would choose the latter. And if someone thinks that some of my binaries suck because there is no support in Y for X, they can build Y with X and use the provided binaries for the rest.

Comment: I would give the advice to use for example ubuntu rather than gentoo in that particular case. For most purposes I believe that building from scratch is NOT meaningful, but if you use gentoo I think that's the admission ticket, period.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my intention.